# odoo 8 tryinig to print without posbox

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have three Epson TM20II Ethernet printers 
trying to print the kitchen orders without the posbox (it's  not available in my country)
I've tried the TAKEPOS solution  :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLBORABL8wA
and many other stuff but nothing seems to work

does anybody has an idea on how to solve this?
I was thinking about emulating the POSBOX on a PC but again I have no idea how to do this ..
many thanks in advance everybody

Answer (score 1):

**Try following:**

1. If you emulate a PC as POSBOX, make sure a printer(EPSON) attached to that
   PC is able to take the printouts.
2. You need to have Odoo running on that PC with the modules of POS
   installed in it and creating database in it. It should install
   following POS modules in it `hw_proxy,hw_escpos,hw_scanner`. Refer to 
   the following link
   https://doc.odoo.com/trunk/hw_proxy/#posboxless-setup-guide
3. Check the IP address of that PC and configure it under the kitchen
   printers section where your original-(main) odoo system is up and running.

**Note:** Just a thought, setup of a this kind is not cost effective, if there are more than one kitchen/bar printers is to be setup, as you need to replace a POSBOX with PC at every place.

Comment: million thanks to your for answering , I have three pcs that should run as POS

Comment: i follow the guide , my OS was windows I've installed a luinx HyperV specficlly to follow the guide , stopped at  launchig the OpenERP server on the port 8069 with the correct database settings:

$ ./server/openerp-server --addons-path=addons,web/addons --db-filter='^posbox$' \
        --xmlrpc-port=8069 -d posbox

as it was raising the error  :-- xmlrpc unrecognized parameters openerp-server

as for the emulating of POSBOX will the VMware be able to run the POSBOX image properly ?

Comment: 1. Sorry but not aware with HyperV linux. 2. First try that your printer is working with those PCs. Just try to follow the guidelines only for printer working. 3. Then try to find, running Odoo from command line using configuration file 4. Find such sample configuration file and try to run Odoo.

Comment: 1. Can you try some debian flavor?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu
the printer works fine with the pc , and it's supported by odoo , (Epson Tm20ii

will try to do as you suggested and feed you right back

thanks !